# Why does production environment return a 200 with empty body?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.2

I have a web developed with Symfony 2.2.1. I developed it using the dev environment and it works great. The problem is when I try the production environment. I receive a 200 with empty body.

My investigation:

Symfony doesn't write nothing in the logs.

`$response = $kernel->handle($request);` is called, but the next line
`$response->send();` it's not. This lines are in the app.php file

If I replace `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);` to `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);` in the app.php file all works great.

What can be wrong with my settings?

I have installed the bundles: FOSRestBundle, FOSUser, Sonata-Admin and Sonata-User.

Comment: have you cleared cache with `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug`?

Comment: I execute a `rm -r app/cache app/logs`. `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug` [doesn't works for me](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataBlockBundle/issues/60)

Comment: Does apache or whatever web server you are using show anything in the logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [@cheesemacfly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1443490/cheesemacfly)! The log:

> `[Wed May 15 18:35:06 2013] [error] [client X.X.X.X] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Exception\\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 'The service "sonata.block.renderer.traceable" has a dependency on a non-existent service "debug.stopwatch".' in /home/inqbarna/ZendProjects/Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php:59\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/inqbarna/ZendProjects/Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php(43): Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Compiler\\CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->processReferences(Array)\n#1 /home/inqbarna/ZendProjects/Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php(37): Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Compiler\\CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->processDefinition(Object(Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Definition))\n#2 /home in /home/inqbarna/ZendProjects/Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php on line 59`

That is, Sonata-Admin requires Sonata-block and this one have a problem.

- The problem is: [The service "sonata.block.renderer.traceable" has a dependency on a non-existent service "debug.stopwatch"](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataBlockBundle/issues/60), and
- the solution is: [[WIP] gracefully handle the absence of the debug.stopwatch service](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataBlockBundle/pull/61).